# encode a nsstring with utf-8Type for post connection

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ios5

Trying to postdata in post connection using setHttpPost

```
NSString* strRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password==%@&client_assertion_type=%@&client_assertion=%@&spEntityID=%@", 
strUsrName,strPasswrd,@"JWT",strAppTknContent,@"http://localhost:8080/opensso"];

NSData* dataRequest = [NSData dataWithBytes:[strRequest UTF8String] length:[strRequest length]];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: dataRequest];
```

want to encode the value for username,password,client_assertion_type alone utf-8 type

```
NSString* username = [ encode utf-8 type @"fff"];
```

how do i encode only the value of each key elements and post it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot encode a string in UTF-8 and then put it in a `NSString` instance. `NSString` uses Unicode characters anyway but not in an encoded form.

Why would you want to encode them separately anyway? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

And just to point out a mistake in your code. The following line does not work once you have characters that require more than 1 byte in UTF-8:

```
NSData* dataRequest = [NSData dataWithBytes:[strRequest UTF8String] length:[strRequest length]];
```

The `length` parameter is expected to be the number of bytes but you are passing the number of characters.

A correct and simpler alternative is:

```
NSData* dataRequest = [strRequest dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
```

**Update**:

As you obviously want to properly URL encoded your parameters, you're probably looking for code like this:

```
NSString* strRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password==%@&client_assertion_type=%@&client_assertion=%@&spEntityID=%@", 
    [strUsrName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
    [strPasswrd stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
    @"JWT",
    [strAppTknContent stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
    [@"http://localhost:8080/opensso" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
];

NSData* dataRequest = [strRequest dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
```

**Update 2:**

It's a very strange design to transmit data that way. When it was first used, it probably was a hack to get something working quickly. Unfortunately, it became a standard.

Basically, you have two levels of encoding. The URL encoding to serves to put several key/value pairs into a single string such that the string can later be split again into the key/value pairs. It needs to know that a UTF-8 encoding is used on the second level so it can escape the problematic characters. It's does UTF-8 the string yet.

The second level translates the string (a sequence of characters) into a byte stream using the UTF-8 encoding since HTTP is specified as a transmission of bytes, not characters.

Comment: im trying to post data in rest service  String content = "username="
     + URLEncoder.encode(username, UTF_8_TYPE) this in java want to do an equivalent in objectiveC

Comment: im encoding   [strUsrName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] and again NSData* dataRequest = [strRequest dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ]; the whole content why??

Comment: As the answer to this question is somewhat complicated and long, I've appended it to my answer (see above).

Comment: "doesnt work" isn't exactly a precise or helpful description of your problem.

Comment: im getting 204 response frm server

Comment: 204 is a success code. Your request was successful. What did you expect? (204 is used if the request is successful but there is no response body needed.)

Comment: im doing nsutf8stringencoding but my data is more than 2500 bytes so thought its returning empty so i used NsLatinostringencoding it din help expected response accept type is application/json